# Cmake: how to include external shared library to static library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to include an external dll to the current cmake project.

External project ext1 package structure

-- include //headers

-- lib  // which has both dll, lib

In the current project,
I am including the libraries of the external ext1 package

```
find_package(ext1 3.1.2 REQUIRED)

include_directories(${ext1 _INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_directories(${ext1 _DIR}/lib)
```

But with the above inclusion, Cmake is only taking the static library from the package.

I also tried invoking linking the dll into the current package. But faced fatal error with trying to open a corrupt dll file.

link_directories(${ext1 _DIR}/lib/a.dll)

Please let me know further how to fix it.

Comment: Dynamic libraries often also have a a small export static library, that is used to call the functions in the dynamic library. Are you sure it's not *that* static library you're linking with?

Comment: Ya sure, since it is linking with sttaic library which is listed in the package.

Comment: Are the spaces in the `ext1 _INCLUDE_DIRS` and `ext1 _DIR` variables also in your CMakeLists.txt or are they a typo? if not remove them, a valid CMake variable name starts with an underscore or letter and must not contain spaces.

Comment: Is the imported target declared as SHARED  in the Find<Package>.cmake / <Package>Config.cmake ? 
Also, you'll need to link against ext1's implib (.lib), and move the dll next to your executable. If you don't have any implib, you can move the dll and load it dynamically in your code at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I did the same as above. But still not sure whether it is linked with the dynamic library properly.

Comment: What package are we talking about? A package that provides a `ext1-config.cmake` and `ext1-exports.cmake` or a package for which `CMake` provides a `Findext1.cmake`?

Comment: Unless `find_package(ext1)` does something unusual, your code **never links** with a library. `link_directories` specifies only a directory where to *search libraries*, linking is performed with `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: In any case show more code, and the **exact error message**. As for "Cmake is only taking the static library from the package." - **How do you know**, that CMake links with a static library? Are you got that from the command line, which invokes the linker, or by some other means?